# My SQL query is way too slow... Someone can check if it is possible to simplfy it ? (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I built this query long ago and it worked well for a long time. Since a couple of weeks, it began to take like 4-5 secs before getting results from the server.

Can you guys check if it is possible to simplify and/or optimize it ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
    SUIVI.administratif.no_suivi,
    SUIVI.administratif.mise_a_jour,
    SUIVI.administratif.date_installation,
    SUIVI.administratif.client_initial,
    SUIVI.actions.type_action,
    type_commande.type_commande,
    SUIVI.type_service.nom_service,
    SUIVI.administratif.statut_suivi,
    SUIVI.administratif.date_received,
    SUIVI.administratif.date_recette,
    SUIVI.administratif.priorite,
    bidon,
    SUIVI.administratif.adresse + ' ' + SUIVI.administratif.ville + ' ' + SUIVI.administratif.code_postal + ' ' + SUIVI.administratif.province AS adresse,
    SUIVI.administratif.derniere_rev,
    SUIVI.administratif.type_de_suivi,
    SUIVI.administratif.date_received_enhanced,
    STUFF((SELECT ' / ' + DESIGN.no_references.no_reference
           FROM DESIGN.no_references
           WHERE DESIGN.no_references.no_suivi = SUIVI.administratif.no_suivi
             AND (DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'FOX'
                  OR DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'SRT'
                  OR DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'OS'
                  OR DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'BC'
                  OR DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'TTO')
           ORDER BY no_reference
           FOR xml path('')), 1, 3, '') AS no_references
FROM   
    (((SUIVI.administratif
INNER JOIN 
    SUIVI.actions ON SUIVI.administratif.no_action = SUIVI.actions.no_action)
INNER JOIN 
    SUIVI.type_commande ON SUIVI.administratif.type_commande = SUIVI.type_commande.no_type_commande)
INNER JOIN 
    SUIVI.type_service ON SUIVI.administratif.type_service = SUIVI.type_service.no_service)
WHERE
    ((adresse_z LIKE '%test%')
     OR (adresse LIKE '%test%')
     OR (client_initial LIKE '%test%')
     OR (type_action LIKE '%test%')
     OR (type_commande.type_commande LIKE '%test%')
     OR (ville_z LIKE '%test%')
     OR (ville LIKE '%test%')
     OR (nom_service LIKE '%test%')
     OR (SUIVI.administratif.no_suivi LIKE '%test%'))
   AND SUIVI.administratif.statut_suivi <> 'Exclu'

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT SUIVI.administratif.no_suivi
                , SUIVI.administratif.mise_a_jour
                , SUIVI.administratif.date_installation
                , SUIVI.administratif.client_initial
                , SUIVI.actions.type_action
                , type_commande.type_commande
                , SUIVI.type_service.nom_service
                , SUIVI.administratif.statut_suivi
                , SUIVI.administratif.date_received
                , SUIVI.administratif.date_recette
                , SUIVI.administratif.priorite
                , bidon
                , SUIVI.administratif.adresse + ' '
                  + SUIVI.administratif.ville + ' '
                  + SUIVI.administratif.code_postal + ' '
                  + SUIVI.administratif.province AS adresse
                , SUIVI.administratif.derniere_rev
                , SUIVI.administratif.type_de_suivi
                , SUIVI.administratif.date_received_enhanced
                , Stuff((SELECT ' / ' + DESIGN.no_references.no_reference
                         FROM   DESIGN.no_references
                         WHERE  DESIGN.no_references.no_suivi = SUIVI.administratif.no_suivi
                            AND ( DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'FOX'
                                   OR DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'SRT'
                                   OR DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'OS'
                                   OR DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'BC'
                                   OR DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'TTO' )
                         ORDER  BY no_reference
                         FOR xml path('')), 1, 3, '') AS no_references
FROM   SUIVI.administratif
       INNER JOIN SUIVI.commandes_equipements ON SUIVI.administratif.no_suivi = SUIVI.commandes_equipements.no_suivi
       INNER JOIN SUIVI.actions ON SUIVI.administratif.no_action = SUIVI.actions.no_action
       INNER JOIN SUIVI.type_commande ON SUIVI.administratif.type_commande = SUIVI.type_commande.no_type_commande
       INNER JOIN SUIVI.type_service ON SUIVI.administratif.type_service = SUIVI.type_service.no_service
WHERE  ( rapport_sap LIKE '%test%' )
   AND SUIVI.administratif.statut_suivi <> 'Exclu'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT SUIVI.administratif.no_suivi
                , SUIVI.administratif.mise_a_jour
                , SUIVI.administratif.date_installation
                , SUIVI.administratif.client_initial
                , SUIVI.actions.type_action
                , type_commande.type_commande
                , SUIVI.type_service.nom_service
                , SUIVI.administratif.statut_suivi
                , SUIVI.administratif.date_received
                , SUIVI.administratif.date_recette
                , SUIVI.administratif.priorite
                , bidon
                , SUIVI.administratif.adresse + ' '
                  + SUIVI.administratif.ville + ' '
                  + SUIVI.administratif.code_postal + ' '
                  + SUIVI.administratif.province AS adresse
                , SUIVI.administratif.derniere_rev
                , SUIVI.administratif.type_de_suivi
                , SUIVI.administratif.date_received_enhanced
                , Stuff((SELECT ' / ' + DESIGN.no_references.no_reference
                         FROM   DESIGN.no_references
                         WHERE  DESIGN.no_references.no_suivi = SUIVI.administratif.no_suivi
                            AND ( DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'FOX'
                                   OR DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'SRT'
                                   OR DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'OS'
                                   OR DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'BC'
                                   OR DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'TTO' )
                         ORDER  BY no_reference
                         FOR xml path('')), 1, 3, '') AS no_references
FROM   SUIVI.administratif
       INNER JOIN SUIVI.liste_ckts_par_suivi ON SUIVI.liste_ckts_par_suivi.no_suivi = SUIVI.administratif.no_suivi
       INNER JOIN SUIVI.actions ON SUIVI.administratif.no_action = SUIVI.actions.no_action
       INNER JOIN SUIVI.type_commande ON SUIVI.administratif.type_commande = SUIVI.type_commande.no_type_commande
       INNER JOIN SUIVI.type_service ON SUIVI.administratif.type_service = SUIVI.type_service.no_service
WHERE  ( SUIVI.liste_ckts_par_suivi.no_ckt LIKE '%test%'
         AND SUIVI.liste_ckts_par_suivi.discard = 0 )
   AND SUIVI.administratif.statut_suivi <> 'Exclu'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT SUIVI.administratif.no_suivi
                , SUIVI.administratif.mise_a_jour
                , SUIVI.administratif.date_installation
                , SUIVI.administratif.client_initial
                , SUIVI.actions.type_action
                , type_commande.type_commande
                , SUIVI.type_service.nom_service
                , SUIVI.administratif.statut_suivi
                , SUIVI.administratif.date_received
                , SUIVI.administratif.date_recette
                , SUIVI.administratif.priorite
                , bidon
                , SUIVI.administratif.adresse + ' '
                  + SUIVI.administratif.ville + ' '
                  + SUIVI.administratif.code_postal + ' '
                  + SUIVI.administratif.province AS adresse
                , SUIVI.administratif.derniere_rev
                , SUIVI.administratif.type_de_suivi
                , SUIVI.administratif.date_received_enhanced
                , Stuff((SELECT ' / ' + DESIGN.no_references.no_reference
                         FROM   DESIGN.no_references
                         WHERE  DESIGN.no_references.no_suivi = SUIVI.administratif.no_suivi
                            AND ( DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'FOX'
                                   OR DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'SRT'
                                   OR DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'OS'
                                   OR DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'BC'
                                   OR DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'TTO' )
                         ORDER  BY no_reference
                         FOR xml path('')), 1, 3, '') AS no_references
FROM   SUIVI.administratif
       INNER JOIN DESIGN.no_references ON DESIGN.no_references.no_suivi = SUIVI.administratif.no_suivi
       INNER JOIN SUIVI.actions ON SUIVI.administratif.no_action = SUIVI.actions.no_action
       INNER JOIN SUIVI.type_commande ON SUIVI.administratif.type_commande = SUIVI.type_commande.no_type_commande
       INNER JOIN SUIVI.type_service ON SUIVI.administratif.type_service = SUIVI.type_service.no_service
WHERE  ( DESIGN.no_references.no_reference LIKE '%test%'
          OR DESIGN.no_references.CSID LIKE '%test%' )
   AND SUIVI.administratif.statut_suivi <> 'Exclu';
```

Comment: If the query hasn't changed them something else has (dropped/altered index for example). Investigate that to get to the root cause.

Comment: Maybe start formatting your query to make it readable by human beings.

Comment: Have you tried using EXPLAIN?

Comment: using 'or' is always slow - avoid if possible - perhaps replace with a union

Comment: I formatted that eyesore into something sort of legible. Your only question is if we can look at it and see "if it is possible to simplify and/or optimize it ". Yes it can simplified. And yes it could be optimized. The task is entirely too much for an online forum. There are so many places where this could be improved. I would suggest you hire a consultant. I would bid this at 1-2 days.

Comment: @DanielMarcus: You mean additionally to the existing three `UNION`s :-)

Comment: lol yes! I have found this usually performs better than or.  Best to rewrite the whole thing from scratch though...

Comment: I should probably add that I am in no way shape or form suggesting you hire me to do this. I would not even entertain taking this on as a contract as that would be a gross abuse of an online forum. You should find somebody local that can come onsite and help.

Comment: Does the server have a maintenance plan that updates database statistics?  Is the maintenance plan scheduled to run?  Is it completing successfully?

Answer (score 1):

You can start by replacing parts of the query like this:

```
 ( DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'FOX'
                                   OR DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'SRT'
                                   OR DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'OS'
                                   OR DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'BC'
                                   OR DESIGN.no_references.type_reference = 'TTO')
```

With this:

```
 ( DESIGN.no_references.type_reference in ('FOX', 'SRT', 'OS', 'BC', 'TTO'))
```

Comment: While that would make it much more readable, `IN` is essentially the same thing as `OR`. It won't improve performance.